# Best practice for mounting/unmounting loopback devices on a network share?

Tags: networking, mount, automount

I am looking for a preferred way to automatically mount and unmount disk images (i.e., loopback files) on a network drive.

Unfortunately `/etc/init.d/umountnfs` does not check for loopback devices. Consequently, the shutdown sequence gets stuck when trying to unmount the network drive hosting the loopback file.

On the other hand, how can I ensure that the loopback file is available on system startup, i.e., how to influence the **sequence of file system mounting during boot**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mount order will typically be determined by the last integer field in `/etc/fstab`. For example:

```
UUID=XXX / ext4    errors=remount-ro,noatime,nodiratime 0 1
```

Here the last integer field will determine the order (the smaller, the earlier). So you probably want nfs mount to have some order here (e.g. 2) and loopback higher than that (e.g. 3). However, with nfs the complication can be that they are mounted only after network devices are fully up and might not happen as part of regular `/etc/init/mountall.conf`. So we must have the loopback device instead tied to interface coming up or down.

This is typically done by scripts in `/etc/network/if-up.d`. But NFS mount will happen in background since it is governed by the upstart job in `/etc/init/mountall-net.conf` which simply sends a signal to mountall to try and reload all network filesystems whenever a network device comes up. It seems that there will be delay after sending signal so I guess a script which will wait like this should work:

```
#!/bin/sh

ntries=10
while [ $ntries -gt 0 ]; do
  if findmnt <nfs-mount-point> >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
    if findmnt <loop-mount-point> >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
      # loop already mounted; nothing to be done
      :
    else
      mount -t loop <loop-file> <loop-mount-point>
    fi
    break
  else
    sleep 1
    ntries="`expr $ntries - 1`"
  fi
done
```

(replace `<nfs-mount-point>`, `<loop-mount-point>`, `<loop-file>` with actual values)
This waits for 10secs in 1sec interval for NFS to be mounted. As I mentioned the natural place to put it in `/etc/network/if-up.d` ordered after the `upstart` script there, but we better launch in background to avoid waiting specially since upstart mount will happen in background via a signal by `/etc/init/mountall-net.conf`. So put this script in say /usr/local/bin, make it executable (allowing to execute even otherwise) and add `/etc/network/if-up.d/zzz-local` (you should first check whether the script works as expected by manually running with `sudo mountloop.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/local/bin/mountloop.sh &
```

(make zzz-local as executable)
The umount is done by `/etc/init.d/umountnfs.sh` sysv task. What we need to do is add a script to umount loop device with an order number less than that. So add `/etc/init.d/umountloop.sh` like:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          umountloop
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:     umountnfs
# Should-Stop:       $network $portmap nfs-common
# Default-Start:
# Default-Stop:      0 6
# Short-Description: Unmount network loop filesystems.
# Description:       Unmount network loop filesystems.
### END INIT INFO

umount <loop-mount-point>
```

(replace  by the actual value and make the script executable)
The order of umountnfs.sh is 31 in my system (`/etc/rc0.d/S31umountnfs.sh`, `/etc/rc6.d/S31umountnfs.sh`), so we will give it a smaller number:

```
sudo update-rc.d umountloop.sh start 30 0 6 .
```

Edit: I made a mistake in the mountloop.sh script before. It should have been `mount -o loop` and not `mount -t loop`. Also the umountloop.sh should have "Default-Start:" as "0 6" and not in "Default-Stop:" in the comments to be accurate though it will not hurt and I mostly copied from umountnfs.sh which has the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, order is decided based on this file:
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
Kindly create one backup of this file and then edit it if needed. Be very careful while editing.
For unmounting a drive,
sudo umount -l mountpoint
or
sudo umount -I mountpoint

Thank you.

Comment: fstab does not seem to have parameters for the precedence of mounting operations. The sequence of configurations in fstab does not help either (does mounting happen simultanously?).